# Как убрать выделение?

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

Как убрать это фиолетовое выделение, из-за него путь читает не так [image: фиолетовое выделение мешает]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, подсветка в IDE неверная и никакое дополнительное экранирование не требуется: https://ideone.com/38GBdj

```
print(r'\\Desktop\\some-file.txt')
print('\\Desktop\\some-file.txt')
print(r'\Desktop\some-file.txt')
```

```
\\Desktop\\some-file.txt
\Desktop\some-file.txt
\Desktop\some-file.txt
```

Во-вторых, путь `\Desktop\some-file.txt` действительно не существует, поскольку это путь относительно корня текущего диска: `C:\Desktop\some-file.txt`. А в варианте `\\Desktop\\some-file.txt` это вообще сетевой путь, где `Desktop` - имя компьютера, а `some-file.txt` должно быть его разделяемым ресурсом. Если убрать начальные слеши, то `Desktop` станет именем папки в текущем каталоге, но и это будет неверно. Правильно так:

```
filepath = r'some-file.txt'
```